# Access tomcat web apps (on ec2) behind ELB using jmx

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tomcat7

I have a tomcat app deployed onto multiple ec2 instances behind ELB ...  Is there any way to access each instance using jmx?  AWS provides any service for it??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to access each instance using jmx?

If each instance has a public IP or Elastic IP, and the appropriate port in the Security Group is open, then you could connect directly, bypassing the ELB. You'll have to go around the ELB somehow in order to connect via JMX. I suggest using a [bastion host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastion_host) and [SSH forwarding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding).

> AWS provides any service for it??

AWS does not provide any service specifically for this. This is just general networking, which is provided by the VPC service.